# Convert long long value to NSTimerInterval

Tags: objective-c

In my iOS project I received a `long long` value which represents a value in milliseconds. I need to convert it to `NSTimeInterval`. How can I convert this value to `NSTimeInterval`?

I know `NSTimeInterval` is a type of `double`, but my value is a `long long` type. I tried:

```
NSTimeInterval *time = longlongvalue / 1000.0;
```

but there is compiler error of imcompatible type, because `NSTimeInterval` is a `double` type, while my value is `long long`.

Comment: That does not really sound like a challenge. NSTimeInterval is a typedef of double. What is your problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know it is a type of double, but my value is a long long type as I have mentioned. I tried `NSTimeInterval *time = value / 1000.0;` but there is compiler error of imcompatible type, because NSTimeInterval is a double type, while my value is long long.

Comment: So, what is the downvote? & why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSTimeInterval` represents seconds, and assuming both values have the same epoch:

```
long long ms = 1234567890LL;
NSTimeInterval interval = ms / 1000.0;
//             ^
//         Remove *
```

Comment: what is the `ms`? Please see my update. your code is what I have already tried that doesn't work.

Comment: It's just some input value.  What you have tried is different and you used `NSTimeInterval *`. And there no need to downvote someone who is attempting to help you.

Comment: OK, actually the `*` is the thing caused my problem. Thanks.Please update your answer to something like "remove the *", I will accept. By the way, I appreciate your help. Downvote in SO doesn't mean I am rude on your help, if you mouse hover the downvote arrow, you will see what does downvote mean(answer is not helpful for problem), though now I realize downvote shouldn't apply here. I will upvote for the reason that your answer is helpful.

Comment: @trojanfoe You don't need to cast `ms` to `NSTimeInterval`, since its automatically promoted to double because of the right hand side of the division.

Comment: @JustSid Yes; that is true; the use of `/ 1000.0` is enough to perform the type conversion.  I will amend.